# Regular expression stored in a variable not working when matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I have a hash of "allowed links" to render on my rails backend, something like this

```
    ALLOWED_URLS = {
      "vimeo": {
          :regex => "/https?:\/\/(?:www\.|player\.)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/(?:\w+\/)?|groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(\d+)\/video\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)/",
},
      "youtube": {
          :regex => "/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/",
    }
```

In each of the stored values, I have a regular expression to try if a link is from youtube or Vimeo and the video id I have tried them both and they work perfectly.

But when I pass that variable to my CoffeeScript and convert it to a JSON, the regex does not work because it comes with quotation marks, like this:

```
"/https?://(?:www.|player.)?vimeo.com/(?:channels/(?:w+/)?|groups/([^/]*)/videos/|album/(d+)/video/|video/|)(d+)(?:$|/|?)/"
```

and when I try to test it, this error is shown...

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //https?://(?:www.|player.)?vimeo.com/(?:channels/(?:w+/)?|groups/([^/]*)/videos/|album/(d+)/video/|video/|)(d+)(?:$|/|?)//: Nothing to repeat
>       at String.matc

I've tried to put the regex without the quotation marks on the backend, but the result is the same

What can I do??

Comment: Store it as a string literal, with appropriate backslash escaping, then use a regexp constructor when you initialize the regex object.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i don't know how to do that, can you show me an example please?

Comment: Or better, store them as Regex literals: `regex: /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|.../` (i.e. drop the surround quotes).

Comment: @muistooshort that doesn't work for me, if I try to access that without the .to_json I get a "missing / (unclosed regex)" error, I think the problem is that I'm using .to_json, but i dont know

Comment: Sorry, missed the CoffeeScript part. Why not just write them in CoffeeScript to begin with? Ruby and JavaScript regexes are different anyway.

Comment: Because my boss told me that he doesn't want to be recompiling the assets every time we add a new allowed link and stored them in a ruby variable ... I don't know what to do @muistooshort

Comment: Fair enough, the boss is always right.

Comment: @AndresFernandes : You don't store regular expressions, you are storing strings. It is correct that the `Regexp` constructor does accept a string for making a regexp out of it, this string then must not contain the `//` regexp delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate problems here:

1. Escaping is going to be a nightmare because everyone (Ruby, (Java|Coffee)Script, regexes) wants to use `\` as an escape character.
2. Converting a dynamic string into a (Java|Coffee)Script regex.

Part (2) is pretty easy, get the regex into a JavaScript string and then use the RegExp constructor in your JavaScript:

```
# In your CoffeeScript...
str = '^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*'
re  = new RegExp(str)
```

So now you need to get this string into your CoffeeScript:

```
'^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*'
```

Build the string in Ruby (using single quotes to reduce the escapes and don't include the leading and trailing slashes):

```
youtube: {
  regex: '^.*(youtu.be/|v/|u/\w/|embed/|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*'
}
```

and then you can use `to_json` to get into JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let str = <%= ALLOWED_URLS[:youtube][:regex].to_json %>;
  let re  = new RegExp(str);
</script>
```

That will be equivalent to saying:

```
let re = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*/;
```

in JavaScript.

Comment: Holy cow, thanks! you're a genius! Thank you so much!

Comment: Again, thank you, I just finished my task, you're my hero!